# Send values ​to excel file [Talend]

Tags: etl, talend

I have a Talend Job that executes an algorithm following an SQL query, using "tjavaflex".
I then store my values ​​in a list of objects.
I would like to send these values to an Excel file.

Here is my job :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO2I1.png)

In tJavaFlex, I have something like this :

```
 java.util.ArrayList<row5Struct> list = new java.util.ArrayList<row5Struct>() ;
 row5Struct row_nv = new row5Struct();
 ...
 ...
 ...
 for( row5Struct elem : list)
    System.out.println(..........)
```

I still can't send data from a tJavaFlex to an Excel file....

Comment: what are you doing exactly in this tJavaFlex, and what kind of data do you want to push into Excel ? It does not seem to be very talend-friendly to have a bunch of java code inside the component

Comment: @Corentin In the tjavaflex, I get the output rows from the sql query, transform/delete them, and keep in a list of objects. I can only go through talend to do what I want...

Comment: why not use a tMap to filter the data and transform it ? This way you'll get to create your output schemas. Talend does not easily work with 'object' , rather with flat type of data, organized in schemas. Given that you want to output to excel file, you should base your work on the schema of your excel file.

Comment: @Corentin But I can't compare the lines with each other with tmap, for example :  
for(int i=0 ; i<list.size() ; i++)
{
    if ( (list.get(i).heure - 1 == list.get(i-1).heure) && ((list.get(i).date).equals(list.get(i-1).date)) ....
}

Comment: You can create a sequence on your mysql output to identify each lines (in a tMap after tMySQLInput, add a row "sequence" with Numeric.sequence("s1",1,1)). push to a tempfile or a cache. Reread your tempfile twice (two tFileInput components) , link them through a tMap. Make an inner join in tMap with sequence to sequence-1, and other related conditions (date, hour,etc).

Comment: Thanks @Corentin, but how do I link the tfileinput with tMap ?, I show you my job in the comments...

Comment: you should edit your original post to add the screenshot of your job, this is not an answer. Just add a second tFileInputDelimited (copy of the first one) , and join the two on tMap (one as the main flow, one as the lookup)